# document on click , exclude elements

Tags: jquery

How do i exclude same element with different class on document click

Click function as follows

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr.player_row', function () {

});
```

I want to exclude the following same type elements that have another class
tr.player_row.locked_starter
tr.player_row.locked_bench

Tried multiple times with variations like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr.player_row , :not("tr.player_row.locked_bench") , :not("tr.player_row.locked_starter")', function () {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) in your event and check class with if condition

```js
$(document).on('click', 'tr.player_row', function () {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("locked_starter") && !$(this).hasClass("locked_bench")) {
    $(this).addClass('special');
  }
});
```

```css
.special { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="player_row">
        <td>player_row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="player_row locked_starter">
        <td>player_row</td>
        <td>locked_starter</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="player_row locked_bench">
        <td>player_row</td>
        <td>locked_bench</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks , i was looking to do something similar but figured i could add in the click function

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly ":not" in selector

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr.player_row:not("tr.player_row.locked_bench,tr.player_row.locked_starter")', function () {
    //Your code
});
```